# Why are my variables not working in the browser and how can I make them global?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

So I want to have variables from app.js available to use in the browser, whilst using a node package. I have two files, index.html and app.js. Browserify then runs using this script `browserify app.js -o bundle.js`. Whenever I try and run a function or access a variable through Dev Tools, it always returns with Reference Error.

I've tried looking online at global variables for Browserify and different scripts to run for Browserify, but still, none of these work. I've also tried adding the original app.js file to index.html and all the variables are accessible before using Browserify.

```
//This is the require section
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  redirectUri: redirectUri,
  clientId: clientId,
  credentials
});

//This for some reason works
var authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);
console.log(authorizeURL);
document.getElementById("url").href = authorizeURL;

//This function will not run with a TypeError
spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant("omitted").then(
  function (data) {
    console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);

    // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body['refresh_token']);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  }
);

//This doesn't work below
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('code');
console.log(myParam);
```

The `spotifyApi` variable isn't appearing at all, the myParam will log, but then I can't access the variable and I used the Browserify script from above.
Also please don't mark this as duplicate, I've already tried different Browserify scripts, marked them as `global.etc` and using Webpack.

Comment: Browserify compiles all source scripts into a single script that wraps everything in a large function. This is by design. The question here is: why do you need to access these variables like that in the first place? Just put your own code into one of the files that get compiled and you can use the module pattern to access anything you like. If you must have access from outside, use `window.myGlobalVar = someInsideVar;`

Comment: Because I have no idea what I'm doing, I just put in all the code inside one file, and thought that Browserify puts the node-modules into to the JS file and replaces all the require() and just automatically referenced the require files in normal JS. How else would I use it then?

Comment: Yes, if a node module is suitable to run in the browser then browserify (or webpack) is the way to use it (because browsers can't all process `require` yet). However this means that your entire code also has to go into the browserify process; in this case into app.js. You saw that your `log()` command worked fine, now you just need to add your other code to app.js, too. It doesn't work like you're used to, where you just add `<script>` tags, then can call everything from the dev tools. If you want test code to run, assign it to a button's `onclick` in app.js.

Comment: So say I have index.html like this:
```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script src="appcodehere.js"></script>
```
How would I reference the spotifyApi variable with all it's functions within appcodehere.js?

Comment: Again: YOU DON'T. That's what I've been trying to tell you. Did you not read any of my comments? If you absolutely must ignore good practice, assign the stuff you need to `window` like I showed in my first comment: `window.spotifyApi = spotifyApi;`

Comment: I understand the part where Browserify only bundles node modules and isn't supposed to be your entire code bundle, but if it only bundles all the modules, how do you actually use them within other JavaScript files?

Comment: `Browserify only bundles node modules` no, you have been bundling your own code together with node modules so far. The only thing you're missing is that you have to put *all your code* inside `app.js`. Again: 1. you put **ALL** your own code in `app.js`. 2. you `require()` whatever modules you need in `app.js` 3. you browserify `app.js` into `bundle.js` like you did and put that in your HTML. That's it.

Comment: Putting this as a separate comment: you **CAN** access the spotify variable, just not in the developer tools or separately included `<script>`s. But you absolutely can inside `app.js`, which is where you're supposed to do it.

Comment: Aah, that's what I was looking for. Thanks